# Android Widget Boilerplate?

Tags: android, android-widget, boilerplate

I'd like to make a prototype of an android widget. Has anyone released a boilerplate that set's up most of the 'widgetness'? And would help me build a simple widget quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want your widget to do. But if you focus on the code parts of the android documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), you have a pretty straightforward description on what needs to be implemented.

Comment: I've programmed for android before, but not on the machine I have now. Anything that would shorten the amount of time before I can say "make a 3x2 widget that shows this content" would be good. I saw those docs before (Something like the first google result) but came here to ask for shortcuts once I realized I didn't know much abou the background there. Going to read through the docs more, maybe things will become clearer. Thanks.